# how to use uniform to change color in webgl

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

So far, I have successfully display a cube with a fix color. However, I want the color of the cube to be changeable. So I tried to replace this code:

```
var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer );
gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(vertexColors1), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );  
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor );
```

with:

```
vColor = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "vColor");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(vColor,false,flatten(vertexColors1));
```

And I also change the type of vColor in my vertex-shader from attribute to uniform. in the fragment shader, I use varying. However, these method is not working. The color of the cube become white instead of the color that I have assigned in vertexColors1. any suggestion?

Shader code:

```
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
uniform  vec4 vColor;
//attribute vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;

void main() 
{
    fColor = vColor;
    gl_Position = modelViewMatrix * vPosition;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>
```

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm sorry, just updated the shader code

Comment: `gl.uniformMatrix4fv(vColor,false,flatten(vertexColors1));` is incorrect; colors are not matrices.

Comment: So, what's colors? I tried, uniform4fv, but it's not working

Comment: `uniform4f`. There may be a `uniform4fv` as well, but I don't know WebGL enough to know for certain.

Comment: Try gl.uniform4fv( vColor, new Float32Array([1, 0, 0, 1]) ), and let us know if it shows up red. Also, what are you trying to accomplish? Setting each vertex to a unique color, or setting one global color for the entire cube?

Comment: it does show red. Do you think it has anything to do with the flatten(vertexcolors1)? I want to set a uniform color to a cube, but I want to be able to change the color of the cube everytime I click it. That's why, I change the attribute type to uniform

Comment: @Pondwater Actually, I just figure it out how to do it. Thanks